# What does the shaded pokéball icon mean?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm not able to catch any Pokemon, I feed them but my pokéball icon is shaded!

[image: Screenshot of pokemon go]

What does this mean, and why won't it let me catch any pokémon?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research effort. How did you manage to run out of Poké Balls without realising?

Answer (score 13):

That blanked out circle means you have no Pokeballs left, and therefore are unable to attempt to catch a pokemon. To get more balls you will have to either purchase some from the store, or find some by spinning pokestops.

Feeding a pokemon berries will not change this, instead they make it easier/more profitable to catch pokemon *when you have pokeballs to use*.